# new to R, and getting this error message, how do I omit NA in my cohort to analyze my data?

Tags: r, na

new to R, and getting this error message, how do I omit NA in my cohort to analyze my data? mean(cohort5$"age.at.diagnosis") [1] NA Warning message: In mean.default(cohort5$age.at.diagnosis) :   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Comment: If you want help, please give a reproducible example. We have no idea what your data looks like. What type of variable is `age.at.diagnosis`? Apparently it isn't numeric. Perhaps it is a factor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do to handle NAs is add `na.rm = TRUE`:

```
mean(cohort5$age.at.diagnosis, na.rm = TRUE)
```

However, the error message you received suggests that the problem is actually in the data format. You should make sure that the variable in your dataframe is, actually, numeric and doesn't contain non-numeric values (for example some unusual character used to indicate missing values). `class(cohort5$age.at.diagnosis)` will tell you the data type.

```
cohort5$age.at.diagnosis <- as.numeric(cohort5$age.at.diagnosis) # if currently character
cohort5$age.at.diagnosis <- as.numeric(as.character(cohort5$age.at.diagnosis)) # if currently factor
```

Both of these lines will coerce non-numeric values into NAs, so be careful because you may be throwing away information by doing that.

Comment: I like how this both answers the question that OP asked and answers the question that they should have asked (but didn't know enough about R to do so). +1

Answer (score 0):

There is are ways to omit missing data prior to running any sort of analysis using the `na.omit` function.

```
na.omit(Cohort5)
```